# Cookies not setting on starlette TestClient, with requests sent via Python Requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, fastapi, starlette

The login/logout feature on FastAPI works in the browser, but I am trying to write unit tests for it. When my app sets the cookie, I can see the response DOES have the cookie sent. When I receive it with Python Request, the cookie has been stripped from the response hence the login doesn't work.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_client():
    app = create_app(testing=True)
    client = TestClient(app)
    client.base_url = 'https://localhost'
    from app.models import Base, User
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    yield client
    db.flush()
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)

# Simple login functions.
def test_login(test_client):
    response = test_client.post(url='/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), allow_redirects=True, proxies=proxies)
    breakpointB()
    assert response.headers
```

Then the server side which works in the browser:

```
    @core.post("/login", response_model=schemas.Token)
    async def login_for_access_token(*, request: Request, form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
                                     db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
        token = jsonable_encoder(access_token)
        response = RedirectResponse(url=request.url_for('index'), status_code=303)
        response.set_cookie(
            "Authorization",
            value=f"Bearer {token}",
            domain=os.environ.get('DOMAIN'),
            httponly=False,
            max_age=1800,
            expires=1800,
        )
        breakpointA()
        return response
```

So at BreakpointA(), just before the response is sent, this is what `response.headers` looks like:

```
MutableHeaders({'location': 'https://localhost/', 'set-cookie': 'Authorization="Bearer e
yJ0eXAiO5JKV1iLCJ4bGciOiJ2UzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOi2b2Vqb2UiL253JleH1iOjE1DM0ODEzNTR7.zwbT9yV
OnV2V14Yrtuc1PP8wv82alz2354sgm0Rc7PgZIvc"; Domain=https://localhost; expires=Fri, 06 Mar 202
0 07:55:54 GMT; Max-Age=1800; Path=/'})
```

At BreakpointB(), on my test client side AFTER the response has been recieved, this is what response.headers and response.cookies looks like:

```
(Pdb) response.headers
{'content-length': '24956', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}

(Pdb) response.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
(Pdb) response.cookies.get_dict()
{}
```

I have a strong suspicion this is because of the domain issue - but how do I correct for this? In my TestClient ([Starlette TestClient](https://www.starlette.io/testclient/)), I have set `client.base_url = 'https://localhost'`, and in my endpoint when making the cookie I've set `DOMAIN=https://localhost`. Anyone have any experience fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. While not a perfect solution, I ended up doing this in my test:

`assert "Authorization" in response.headers['set-cookie']`

...you could check for more things in the string as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue, in my case, it is indeed because of the cookie domain used in `TestClient`.

You can supply your cookie_domain as the `base_url` to your `TestClient`:

```
client = TestClient(app, base_url="http://example.com")
```

`set-cookie` should work as long as the base_url is consistent with the cookie domain.

Edit: make sure your cookie domain is an FQDN without `http://` or `https://` prefixes

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I set the `max_age` parameter of the cookie to `float`, instead of `int`. It was failing to parse the cookie because of that.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem and none of the above solutions worked for me. What I ended up doing just for testing purposes is modifying my cookie-setting code in my FastAPI server:

```py
response.set_cookie(
  # ... other params
  domain=domain if domain != "testserver" else None
)
```

Then the `TestClient` responses had the cookies set as expected.